# Clicking Menu of external application using pinvoke c#

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I am trying to create a app which uses winapi using pinvoke, this application reads menu structure of notepad. I got the whole menu structure using **"GetSubMenu"** and getting the text of menuitem using **"GetMenuString"**

In my app, I created same menu structure based on the structure I got from notepad. I would like to create functionality in my application such that when a user clicks on menu in my application it will click the corresponding menu in the notepad. How can I achieve this, I have tried tons of things but nothing seems to work. I tried using *SendMessage*, *PostMessage* but not sure how to use them.

Sorry if I have asked an already asked question, but a guidance would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**:
As I said I create menu structure based on the menu structure I get from Notepad using GetMenuString, I want to send click to the menuitem in Notepad using MenuItemID, I don't want to click on particular coordinates, but on a particular menu.

Comment: I smell XY, what's the behavior you're after ? Can you provide a sample usage scenario (complete with what the user will do, and what the outcome will be) ?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have updated the description. My main requirement is to send click to a menu item in external application. This would be to the menu item using menuitemID not using xy coordinates of mouse. Can you please give some basics of it.